# How do I find the missing amounts between different months?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So my problem is this, currently I have an amount of money with start date and end date. I'm able to calculate the beginning month and end month money but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out the in between months amount. Then once figuring that out to combine all three equations into a single situation to be able to type in any start date, any end date, then amount that automatically calculates for each given month automatically.

The table looks like this:
[image: Sheet1]
As you can see it calculates May and August by pasting the calculations into those cells manually. But, I'm not able to figure out how to calculate the middle portion then putting the formula into one single formula to be able to automatically calculate.

The code that I currently have to calculate May is:

```
=(MAXIFS(Dates!$A:$A,Dates!$B:$B,VLOOKUP($B$2,Dates!$A:$C,2))-$B$2)/($B$3-$B$2)*$B$4
```

This calculation is essentially if the start date is on 5/26/2019 start at that date, to only calculate 6 days for this example. Then calculate the amount needed for those 6 days.

The August Formula is:

```
=IF($B$3<=MAXIFS(Dates!$A:$A,Dates!$B:$B,VLOOKUP($B$3,Dates!$A:$C,2)),($B$3-MINIFS(Dates!$A:$A,Dates!$B:$B,VLOOKUP($B$3,Dates!$A:$C,2))+1)/($B$3-$B$2)*$B$4,"No")
```

This does the same as May where when it ends, in this case 8/15/2019 it only calculates up until 8/15/2019 and not the entire fiscal month.

The Dates sheet looks like this:

[image: Dates_Sheet]

This is just a sample of the data as the sheet itself is too big to show in a picture. But here is how it lays out for a Fiscal Year:

[image: Fiscal_Year]

What I want the end result to look like is:

[image: End_Result]

But also to have it automatic where anyone could enter in Start Date/End Date/Amount and it auto calculates everything for the person. The dates can go from February - January or just a single month as well.

Any help would be much appreciated and if anything needs to be expanded on please let me know as I'm not sure how to ask a question for this specific problem.

Thanks in advance,

-Maykid

Comment: how does excel know that the month names in M and N are in 2020 and not 2019?  They appear to only be the names of the months.

Comment: @ScottCraner For the Fiscal Year it runs from February - January. The end date would calculate for 2020 portion ex.: End Date: 1/5/2020, but if needed the Month names can change if it would future proof the formula. I'm completely open to any changes or ideas.

Comment: I get a different result for August.  If you do not count the 15th it is 14*771.6049383
 which equals 10802.46914 and if you include it the total is 11574.07407.

Comment: @ScottCraner for August it would be: 8/15/2019 - 8/4/2019 = 11 + 1 (To include the end of the last day) 12, 12/81 (Total Days) = .148148148 * 62500 = $9,259.26 is how I got that calculation.

Comment: Seems to me that you need to do inclusive counting. IOW, shouldn't you be counting 7 days for a start of 5/26/2019?  26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1-Jun

Comment: see edit to my answer I missed you had a lookup with the fiscal month names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array formula:

```
=SUM(if(LOOKUP(row(index($XFD:$XFD,$B$2):index($XFD:$XFD,$B$3)),Dates!$A:$A,Dates!B:B)=C$1,$B$4/($B$3-$B$2)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Put in C2, hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter then copy over.

Comment: When I try putting into C2 and making it an array it gives me an error for some reason: `Microsoft Excel cannot calculate a formula. There is a circular reference in an open workbook, but the references that cause it cannot be listed for you. Try editing the last formula you entered or removing it with the Undo command.` Is there something I'm doing wrong? I'm copying and pasting into the cell and before anything CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and gives me that specific error.